# Retaining browser state on form when synchronising with server in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, api, angularjs

I have a HTML form which is backed by an `ngModel` of an object called `a`. When the user enters data into the form, the resource is updated on the server with a PUT request. I need to use the data which the server returns from this request to update/replace my local data, as things like `lastModified` will have changed.

Replacing the whole object like `a = b` (where `b` is the server response) causes the whole HTML form to re-render because, as far as `ngModel` is concerned, it has an entirely new object. This is also bad because it means that, if the user has an input focused, the input will lose its focus when the form re-renders.

I have written a function to recursively add/delete/update the keys on my `a` object whilst retaining all references, thus circumventing the re-render. However I have a feeling this is a bad approach. Is this a common issue in Angular, and how else can I work around it? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Update:** I don't have `ngModel` on my form. Rather, the form is a iteration element inside of an `ngRepeat`.

Answer (score 1):

First to clarify - I hope you don't have an ngModel on your form but rather on each input of the form?

Now to the helpful bit: do you know of angular.extend? It is used to extend a destination object by values from a source object, keeping the references.
Referring to your 'a'-object and your 'b' response-object it could be as simple as:

```
angular.extend(a, b);
```

There's also a more powerful jQuery equivalent by the same name. (Don't forget your digest/apply calls, though, when you use the jQuery one).

http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/angular.extend

You might also want to look into handling resources in a more structured way. This bit should be of particular interest:

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering, once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the new data.

http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ngResource.$resource

Comment: Oops, I don't have an `ngModel` on my form. My mistake for not explaining the problem correctly. Actually, I am using the `ngRepeat` directive on some data, and `a` is an element inside of that repeat. `extend` would fix this, however if I then repeat on data inside of that object (i.e. `ng:repeat="element in a.elements"`) then `extend` would override that data (each `element` object), thus breaking the reference and causing Angular to re-render.

Comment: Have you tried jquery deep extend? There should be a flag for that. Sorry, just guessing, but without the actual code it's a bit of a guessing game.